# Jquery append to specific div with specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, sockets, append

I'm creating a web chat using socket.io with individual windows with users. And I want to append message only to specific user(window) so each windows when created has attribute dataid so when I click send I'm resolving the id of the windows like this:

```
var id = $(this).closest(".chat").data("dataid"); 
console.log(id);
```

This is working, when I click send it finds closes chat and give me the id which I just use with socket io to send the message.

Now I'm working on receiving the message but I have a problem, because u don't know who will write you so I want to select the div with class chat by dataid and find div conversation, but this is not working.

`$('.chat[data-dataid="1"]').find('conversation').append('hello man');` 
Thank you for your help

Comment: You have an element `<conversation>`?

Comment: would be great if you can create fiddle.

Comment: This is why socket IO supports rooms.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed something in your .find() call, like a dot (.) if you refer a class or e # if you refer an ID

Answer (score 0):

If you don't append any text to conversation, it wont change the background color, because it has no height.  you have to add min-height.

```
div.chat
{
  min-height:20px;
}
```

here is the **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Nztak/